# boolean VB expression returning false for integer 1

Tags: vb.net

This is probably a really basic (no pun intended) question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.  Why does the result of func1 return False and func2 returns True?  On every other test I have done, integer 1 is converted to boolean true and 0 to false.  Works ok if I just set rtnValue to 1 or 0.

```
Public Function func1() As Boolean
    Dim rtnValue As Integer = 0
    Return rtnValue = 1

End Function


Public Function func2() As Boolean
    Dim rtnValue As Integer = 0
    Return rtnValue = 0

End Function
```

Comment: The = operator can be used both in an assignment statement and as the equality operator in an expression.  You are getting the expression version.  1 = 0  is False.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are doing in "Return rtnValue = 1" is actually comparing whether rtnValue is equal to 1, not setting rtnValue to 1 and then returning rtnValue.

Answer (score 1):

You are dangerously mixing up types.  In VB, the integer 1 is integer 1, not boolean true.  Same goes for integer 0 and boolean false.

In addition, your func1() is checking to see if rtnValue is equal to 1.  If it is, then your function returns true.  If not, it returns false.  In your case, you set rtnValue to 0, and since 0 does not equal 1, it returns false.

Your func2() returns true because rtnValue is equal to 0, which is what you are testing.

Comment: That "type mixing" happens, I believe, thanks to C. For the C programming language, anything that evals zero is false, and anything that evals non-zero is true.

Answer (score 0):

You are retuning an expression check, it appears. Thus it will report as `true` when `Return rtnValue = 0` because `rtnValue` is indeed `0`.